# How to install third party component in CQ5

Tags: adobe, components, aem, day-cq

I am new to Adobe CQ5. I have downloaded Google Map components. But i dont know how to make the component to appear in sidekick box.

Please any one suggest the link or the steps to install the third party components.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that if you have any group for the component is selected in the Design mode and also the component is having a "cq:Dialog" or "cq:editConfig" node

Comment: i didnt installed the component yet. Please suggest how to install downloaded component to CQ5

Comment: did your issue resolve? If yes and any answer has been useful, please choose the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

As @VAr has suggested, you will first have to create a component in CQ. For any component to appear in Sidekick it has to have either have a dialog or a cq:EditConfig type of node and name of cq:editConfig, do mention a component group while you create a component.
Once you have this configuration ready, you will have to edit the jsp of component.
Now, go to design mode using sideKick and find the component group in which you set while creating the component. Click on the checkbox next to the component you created and component will appear in sidekick.

You will find the component either in Other group or in the component group. If you find the component in Other group that means that the component group in which you placed your component does not contain at least 5 (don't remember exactly) components.

Hope that answered your query.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps i have followed to embed the googleMap component.

1. Create a component:
2. Create a dialog:
3. go to the URL
   http://www.embedgooglemap.com/
   Generate the code with CreateMap
4. Copy and paste the code in to the newly created component JSP.
   Make sure that if any component Group (if you have) is enabled in the Design Mode.
5. Drag and drop the component into the page from sidekick.[image]